# Leetcode 28. Implement strStr() -- Why my code failed?

Tags: debugging

My code failed on haystack = "hello", needle = "ll".
Expected: 2, my output: -1.

Here's my code:

```
class Solution {
public int strStr(String haystack, String needle) {
    if (needle.length() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    String result = "";
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (i < haystack.length() && j < needle.length()) {
        if (haystack.charAt(i) == needle.charAt(j)) {
            result += needle.charAt(j);
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        result = "";
        i++;
    }
    if (result.equals(needle)) {
        return i - needle.length();
    }
    return -1;
}
```

}

What did I miss?
Thank you!

Comment: One problem I can see is that you always set `result = ""`, even if the condition in the `if` is true.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
public int strStr(String haystack, String needle) {
    if (needle.length() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    String result = "";
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (i < haystack.length() && j < needle.length()) {
        if (haystack.charAt(i) == needle.charAt(j)) {
            result += needle.charAt(j);
            i++;
            j++;
        } else {
            result = "";
            i++;
        }
    }
    if (result.equals(needle)) {
        return i - needle.length();
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I think this is what you expect.
in your answer, when `haystack.charAt(i) == needle.charAt(j)` is okay, you add the `needle.charAt(j)` to result, and you set result empty string. That's why you are wrong.
so, in the end, the result is empty, and return -1;